# C TOR Socket Not Sending Request

Tags: c, sockets, networking, proxy, tor

I'm trying to make a C program that uses a socket through a TOR proxy server to send a GET request to a site that the user passes through as they run the program. The program compiles perfectly and it connects and communicates fine but the server keeps returning an error when it tries to send the request to the domain.

I have tried a few ways of fixing it but none seem to work so far. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(!argv[1]) {
            printf("Usage: %s [HOST]\n",argv[0]);
            exit(1);
    }

    char *host = argv[1];
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.20"); //TOR server address
    server.sin_port = htons( 9050 );

    connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));

    char request1[3] = (char []) { 0x05, 0x01, 0x00 };
    send(s, request1, 3, 0);

    char response1[2];
    recv(s, response1, 2, 0);

    short port = htons(80);
    char host_len = (char)strlen(host);
    char* request2[4+1+host_len+2];
    char tempRequestHolder[4] = (char []) { 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03 };

    memcpy(request2, tempRequestHolder, 4);
    memcpy(request2 + 4, &host_len, 1);
    memcpy(request2 + 5, host, host_len);
    memcpy(request2 + 5 + host_len, &port, 2);

    send(s, (char *)request2, 4 + 1 + host_len + 2, 0);

    char response2[10];
    recv(s, response2, 10, 0);

    char * request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    char buf[2048];
    unsigned int rec = recv(s, buf, 2048, 0);

    printf("\n%s\n",buf);

    return 0;
}
```

When it runs:

```
./tor-client some-site.com
```

The TOR server returns this error:

```
[warn] Your application (using socks5 to port 0) gave Tor a malformed hostname: [scrubbed]. Rejecting the connection.
```

I'm having trouble figuring out as to why this is happening and have tried a few way to fix it, but no luck. Any help/reply will be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: If you change your declaration of `request2` to `char request2[4+1+host_len+2];` the memcpy will work.   char * asdf != asdf[]  It's important to realize that they are different.  A char * asdf; is an address while asdf[] is a preallocated set of bytes

Comment: Here's some nice code to look at for how to do it in a slightly easier way than the memcpy's and is also endian safe for sending the port: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/socks.c#L585

Comment: @drew010 Whoops! I didn't see that... thank you!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @drew010 Update: It worked! Thanks a lot dude I feel like an idiot for not seeing that :/ rookie mistake.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I had to run the program and looked at a few other things before noticing the `*`.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

At `memcpy(request2 + 4, &host_len, 1);` the last argument '1' is the length of the buffer. You shouldn't pass it as a constant because it depends on the length of the buffer of the domain name length.

The Tor's Socks5 Proxy cares about the domain name length, if you send '1' instead of '13' as the domain name length it will read 's' instead of 'some-site.com' even if you sent the entire domain name.

The solution is :
`memcpy(request2 + 4, &host_len, strlen(host_len));`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so.